# XOR of two strings of 0s and 1s

Tags: c++, string, xor

I have two arrays of strings with strings containing just 0s and 1s. I have to XOR the elements of the array that is I have to XOR two strings and store the result in a third array. How should I proceed?

Example. string A[],B[],C[]

A[] = {'101','100'} ,B[] = {'110'} so the output should be the array C[] = {'011','010'}

Do I have to XOR individual elements of the string and hence XOR the two strings or there is a way to directly XOR both of them?

It was a part of a test I just had. I wrote the code there and there was a function I had to complete containing the two argument vectors. I was getting an error of unrecognized operator ^ when I tried to do something like A[i]^B[i].

Comment: Where is your effort?

Comment: you dont do a XOR on an string, you do that on a primitive type a char containing 3 characters will have 24 bytes and not 3 bits.

Comment: It was a part of a test I just had. I wrote the code there and there was a function I had to complete containing the two argument vectors. I was getting an error of unrecognized operator ^ when I tried to do something like A[i]^B[i]. Therefore i asked.

Comment: If you're using character arrays for 1's and 0's why not use an integer to  put them in? that way you 'directly' XOR both of them.

Comment: @Ayush Goyal  What is the type of the arrays?

Comment: Hint: `char(c ^ d ^ '0')` is probably the fastest way to XOR 2 chars `c` and `d`.

Comment: The arguments of the function are the string vectors

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus So I have to loop through all the characters of the strings individually and store the XOR to a third string and then return it ?

Comment: @AyushGoyal I am sure you question should be closed that next time you would write question clear.

Comment: @AyushGoyal One more show how the arrays are declared. Is it clear?

Comment: @vladfrommoscow Sorry for the inconvenience. I could not get the code since it was a part of the test I just had. I just remembered the problem I was having. I am still new to stackoverflow and hence bad at asking questions.

Comment: @AyushGoyal: something like this. As far as I am aware, there is no way to XOR whole strings at once. You can also try simpler `char((c != d) + '0')`, or `(c == d)?: '0', '1'` . Now go try to write it, if you'll get stuck, then, if you'll be unable to solve your problem searching the web, it'll be perfect time to ask good question!

Comment: *"First comes right, then comes fast."* Try to XOR two chars, '0' and '1'. When you can do that, try two strings. When you understand the problem better, you can think about shortcuts.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I had to complete a function whose arguments were two string vectors. So the array I am talking about here are array/vector of strings.

Comment: @AyushGoyal Do you understand this phrase "Show the definitions of the array"? How many times is it needed to repeat?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Thanks for the advise. I will try this and next time I will only come up with good questions for sure and will not waste time of anyone. Sorry again to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't simply XOR two strings like this `str1 ^ str2` (^ is not overloaded for strings to do this).

Iterate over the strings and XOR the chars step by step. You will even need to 'implement the XOR on chars' yourself (since ^ is a bit-wise XOR which is not what you want judging from your sample).

You could do something like `c[i] = a[i]==b[i] ? '0' : '1'`. Or some kind of bit-fiddling would work too I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Building on GingerPlusPlus's comment, you could XOR two equal length strings of 0's and 1's using:

```
std::string xor_str( const std::string& a, const std::string& b )
{
    std::string c( a.size(), '0' );
    std::transform( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), c.begin(),
            [] ( char x, char y ) { return x ^ y ^ '0'; } );
    return c;
}
```

and call this using:

```
std::cout << xor_str("0101", "0110") << std::endl;
```

output:

```
0011
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, seems that you made an error in the datatype.
If you write

```
A[] = {'101','100'}
```

You let me understand that A, is not an array of bits. So, operator ^ cannot be applied.

Comment: Yeah. I was in a hurry in the test and also I am new to programming in general. Therefore I just tried whatever I knew in the test. It was my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert them to bitsets.
Assuming that you want to compute the XOR of the first set by the second

```
   #include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  const size_t numbits = 3;

  std::vector<std::bitset<numbits>> b1;
  std::vector<std::bitset<numbits>> b2;

  std::bitset<numbits> b11 (std::string("101"));
  std::bitset<numbits> b12 (std::string("100"));

  b1.push_back(b11);
  b1.push_back(b12);

  std::bitset<numbits> b21 (std::string("110"));

  b2.push_back(b21);

  std::vector<std::bitset<numbits>> res;

  res.reserve(b1.size()*b2.size());

  std::bitset<numbits> xorres;

  for(size_t i = 0; i < b1.size(); i++)
    {
      for(size_t j = 0; j < b2.size(); j++)
    {
      xorres = (b1[i]^= b2[j]);
      res.push_back(xorres);
    }

    }


  for(size_t k = 0; k < res.size(); k++)
    {
      std::cout << "RES N" << k <<" " << res[k] << std::endl;
    }


}
```

Yielding the result

```
RES N0 011
RES N1 010
```